# scroll height is greater than height of inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, lazy-loading

I have a scrollable div set up as an outer div with overflow-y set to "scroll", and an inner div that overflows.

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 300px;">
  <div style="height: 23500px;">
     <Children />
  </div>
</div>
```

I am writing a script that lazy loads child elements, so the position of each child is calculated with a css `transform: translate`. The height of each child is 50px, and the transforms increment by 50px based on the index of the child. The children don't have any other positional offsets.

Expected result: the outer div stops scrolling at the end of the inner div.

Actual result: there is always about 20px of extra space at the end of the scroll. If I inspect the element, I can see that the outer div is scrolling past the inner div.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: what is the reason behind adding a set height of 23500px to the inner div? If the <Children /> component is larger than 300px it will overflow automatically.

Comment: I am only rendering the visible content to the DOM, so the height setting makes the div scrollable

Comment: The height is calculated based on the number of children: 23500 / 50 = 470 children.

Comment: By any chance are you using any margin or padding inside the <Children /> component? That can effect the parent div's spacing.

Comment: Not that I know of